# highstock chart readjust chart extremes using setextremes and aftersetextremes

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a question about highstock chart's extremes, I would like to reset a chart's extremes after zooming in the chart by using mouse selecting an area in the chart.

For example,

In the chart the minimum interval of my data is 1 hour. If I select an area that from `2:30 to 3:30`, I can see that area is zoomed in (the chart extremes start from `2:30 to 3:30`). But I would like to adjust the chart extreme to (`min:2:00 and max:4:00`) so that I could see the chart starts exactly at `2:00` rather than `2:30`).

If I do `setExtremes(roundingDown(e.min),roundingUp(e.max))` (to adjust the chart extremes) inside event.setExtremes, it seems like enter an infinite loop.

```
xAxis.events.setExtremes = function(e){
            //e.min is 2:30 and e.max is 3:30 after zoom in;
            this.chart.xAxis.setExtremes(roundingDown(e.min),roundingUp(e.max)) // this reset the extremes to min:2:00 and max 4:00
}
```

Hope my description is clear and I appreciate any the hints and help.

The data looks like the data in this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/PEXmz/

Comment: I hope you are not surprised about infinite loop? ;) Calling setExtremes in setExtremes callback which calls setExtremes etc etc etc. Call this setExtremes only when necessary, just once.

Comment: @PawełFus Can we use afterSetExtremes to solve this problem?

Comment: But it will be the same issue: if you call setExtremes in afterSetExtremes, which will call another setExtremes etc. As I said, call it just once, add some condition to check whether you need to update those extremes.